# How can I obtain the title of a youtube video from only the url?

Tags: java, api, youtube

I am writing a program in java in which my program is only given the url of a youtube video, but I would like to output the title of the video which the url references. Is there any API or other method I can use to solve this? thank you.

Comment: https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos/list see if it helps

Comment: Refer the following link on how to use the the youtube api.
[Youtuve api-samples](https://github.com/youtube/api-samples/tree/master/java)

Answer (score 0):

According to official youtube api [docs](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/getting-started). First, you need to get your API_KEY. Then hit below endpoint (with YOUR_API_KEY and YOUR_VIDEO_ID)

```
https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos?id=YOUR_VIDEO_ID&key=YOUR_API_KEY
 &part=snippet,contentDetails,statistics,status
```

You will recieve a JSON object as a response like this

```
{ 
  "kind": "youtube#videoListResponse",
  "etag": "\"UCBpFjp2h75_b92t44sqraUcyu0/sDAlsG9NGKfr6v5AlPZKSEZdtqA\"",
  "videos": [
      {
        "id": "7lCDEYXw3mM",
        "kind": "youtube#video",
        "etag": "\"UCBpFjp2h75_b92t44sqraUcyu0/iYynQR8AtacsFUwWmrVaw4Smb_Q\"",
        "snippet": { 
        "publishedAt": "2012-06-20T22:45:24.000Z",
        "channelId": "UC_x5XG1OV2P6uZZ5FSM9Ttw",
        "title": "Google I/O 101: Q&A On Using Google APIs",
        "description": "Antonio Fuentes speaks to us and takes questions on working with Google APIs and OAuth 2.0.",
        "thumbnails": {
        "default": {
        "url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/7lCDEYXw3mM/default.jpg"
     },
  "medium": {
      "url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/7lCDEYXw3mM/mqdefault.jpg"
  },
  "high": {
      "url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/7lCDEYXw3mM/hqdefault.jpg"
  }
},
   "categoryId": "28"
},
   "contentDetails": {
      "duration": "PT15M51S",
      "aspectRatio": "RATIO_16_9"
},
  "statistics": {
      "viewCount": "3057",
      "likeCount": "25",
      "dislikeCount": "0",
      "favoriteCount": "17",
      "commentCount": "12"
  },
 "status": {
    "uploadStatus": "STATUS_PROCESSED",
    "privacyStatus": "PRIVACY_PUBLIC"
   }
  }
  ]
}
```

You can get all info, including title.

Answer (score 0):

If you must do it without YouTube's API, I'd recommend scraping the `<title>` tag off the webpage - that's likely easier than finding the `div` that contains the title, although you may miss some emojis or the like. For a pure Java solution, I'd just use the builtin method for http requests, `java.net.HttpURLConnection`, then stream the response data until you reach `<title>` and use the next part as a string until `- YouTube</title>`.

Here's a brief example (you'd probably want to do exception handling and the like).

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;

public class YouTubeTitleScraper
{
  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
  {
    URL url = new URL("https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IYnsfV5N2n8");
    HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
    con.setRequestMethod("GET");
    BufferedReader read = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(con.getInputStream()));
    boolean found = false;
    String line;
    while (!found)
    {
      line = read.readLine();
      if (line.contains("<title>"))
      {
        found = true;
        System.out.println("Title: " + line.substring(7, line.indexOf(" - YouTube</title>")));
      }
    }
    read.close();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using maven and want to use Jsoup, add these add a dependency

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jsoup</groupId>
            <artifactId>jsoup</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.2</version>
        </dependency>
```

or if not , just add the jar you find [here](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.jsoup/jsoup/1.7.2) to your classpath, so that it will be available to your code.

Then it is as simple as below:

```
import java.io.IOException;

import org.jsoup.Jsoup;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Document;

public class Test {

  public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    Document document = Jsoup.connect("https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eIrMbAQSU34").get();
    String title = document.title().replaceAll(" - YouTube$", "");
    System.out.println(title);
  }
}
```

in this case it prints:

> Java Tutorial for Beginners [2019]